# Django - writing an hebrew string

Tags: python, django, parsing, encoding, hebrew

I'm trying to send an hebrew string through parse rest API in a Django code 
**the code is fine - sending a string in english works perfectly** 
when the letters are in hebrew I get the following error:

```
Non-ASCII character '\xd7' but no encoding declared;
```

how can I set encoding programmatically for a specific line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code):

> Python supports writing Unicode literals in any encoding, but you have
>   to declare the encoding being used. This is done by including a
>   special comment as either the first or second line of the source file

In your case:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```